# Why does my JButton action listener execute double the amount of times before?

Tags: java, swing, loops, user-interface, actionlistener

I'm currently setting up a quiz program right now, where the code will loop 20 times. There are 20 question, 80 answers (4 to each question) and the program will set JButtons and action listeners to listen for the user's answer for each question, then call the original quiz loop again from the correct or incorrect answer.

However, the program I'm having is that the program will display question 1, then question 2, but then question 4, 8, 16 and finally 20 since it cannot double anymore.

I've tried:

- Breakpointing the value of the **currentQuestion** variable, as I believe this is the one which is doubling and causing the problem.
- Creating a new method named **updateQuestionAndAnswer** to ensure that it's not a misclick.
- Removing the other three action listeners, which helped me to find that it was whatever action listener that I clicked that was repeatedly being called. E.g if it was on Question 8 and I clicked listener 3, it would call listener 3 another 8 times.

I've enclosed the code below I think will be useful. All variables that you cannot see defined within here, are defined to 0 or "" in a static context outside of methods at the top of my program.

````
     * Defines and places all of the content for the Game page. 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public void setupGamePanel() throws IOException {
        // Game page card constructor
        card2 = new JPanel() {
            // Make the window the specified sizes
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
                size.width += extraWindowWidth;
                size.height += extraWindowHeight;
                return size;
            }
        };
        // JAVA COMPONENT DEFINITIONS
        String[] openingDialogue = new String[]{"<html><span style='font-size:20px;'>We need your help. After Junko Enoshima took over Hope’s Peak Academy, she trapped the entire of Class 78 inside a monstrous killing game! My creator, Chihiro Fujisaki, is one of them.", "<html><span style='font-size:20px;'>I managed to patch into the systems that the Ultimate ******** setup when he fell into despair, but we’ve been hit with a security system implemented by Jin Kirigiri before he…", "<html><span style='font-size:20px;'>Anyway, we need to get a good enough score out of twenty quiz questions in order to get inside the network, where my creator should be waiting for me.", "<html><span style='font-size:20px;'>Let’s do this. Answer the questions as best as you can. Good luck.", ""};

        // Score counter
        scoreCounter.setText("<html><span style='font-size:30px;'>Score: " + String.valueOf(score) + "</html>");

        // Alter ego dialogue text
        dialogueText = new JLabel("");
        dialogueText.setText("<html><span style='font-size:20px;'>You’re...actually here? You survived. You're inside the first versions of the Neo World Program!</html>");

        // Buttons
        beginButton = new JButton("BEGIN THE GAME!");
        continueButton = new JButton("Continue Dialogue");

        // Images
        alterEgoImage = ImageIO.read(new File("AlterEgo/alterego.png"));
        BufferedImage alterEgoNeutral = ImageIO.read(new File("AlterEgo/neutral.jpeg"));

        alterEgoImageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(alterEgoImage));

        // X, Y. Width, Height
        alterEgoImageLabel.setBounds(510, 150, 550, 300);
        scoreCounter.setBounds(15, 15, 250, 40);
        beginButton.setBounds(650, 480, 250, 40);
        continueButton.setBounds(650, 480, 250, 40);
        dialogueText.setBounds(500, 490, 750, 300);

        // Allows for a more dynamic and fluid layout of the page where bounds are specified.
        card2.setLayout(null);

        // Add the components to the page
        card2.add(beginButton);
        card2.add(continueButton);
        card2.add(dialogueText);
        card2.add(scoreCounter);
        card2.add(alterEgoImageLabel);

        continueButton.setVisible(false);
        dialogueText.setVisible(false);

        // BEGIN THE QUIZ GAME

        // Game begins when the button is clicked
        beginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    beginButton.setVisible(false);
                    continueButton.setVisible(true);
                    dialogueText.setVisible(true);
                }
            });

        // Continue the opening dialogue with the continue button, and immediately begin the quiz after the dialogue has finished.
        continueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dialogueText.setText(openingDialogue[openDialoguePos]);
                    openDialoguePos++;
                    if(openDialoguePos == openingDialogue.length) {
                        continueButton.setVisible(false);
                        dialogueText.setVisible(false);

                        // SET THE ALTER EGO IMAGE TO THE NEUTRAL ONE TO BEGIN THE GAME

                        try {
                            quizProcess();
                        } catch(IOException excep) {
                            // Handle the error here
                        }
                        //quizProcess();
                    }
                }
            });
    } // end setupGamePanel()

    /**
     * Defines and places all of the content for the leaderboard page.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void setupLeaderboardPanel() throws IOException {
        // Leaderboard page card constructor
        card3 = new JPanel();

        card3.add(new JTextField("TextField", 20));
    } // end setupLeaderboardPanel()

    /**
     * The top level method for the quiz game.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void quizProcess() throws IOException {
        // TOP LEVEL METHOD BEGINS
        setupQuizUI(answerButtons);

        readData(questions, answers);

        quizLoop(questions, answers, answerButtons);
    }

    public void quizLoop(String questions[], String[] answers, JButton[] answerButtons) {
        System.out.println("A quiz loop is being initiated");
        
        moveOntoNextQuestion(questions, answers, answerButtons);
        //assignData();
        checkCorrectQuestion(answerButtons);
    }

    /**
     * Initialise and setup the answer buttons and question text.
     */
    public void setupQuizUI(JButton[] answerButtons) {
        // Alter ego dialogue text
        questionText.setText("<html><span style='font-size:20px;'<</html>");
        questionText.setBounds(550, 450, 350, 150);
        card2.add(questionText);

        //System.out.println("Fifth read: " + currentQuestion + 25);

        for(int i = 0; i < answerButtons.length; i++) {
            answerButtons[i] = new JButton("Test");
        }

        // Bound setting (X, Y, Width, Height)
        answerButtons[0].setBounds(150, 580, 200, 100);
        answerButtons[1].setBounds(550, 580, 200, 100);
        answerButtons[2].setBounds(950, 580, 200, 100);
        answerButtons[3].setBounds(1350, 580, 200, 100);

        // Adding to the JFrame
        card2.add(answerButtons[0]);
        card2.add(answerButtons[1]);
        card2.add(answerButtons[2]);
        card2.add(answerButtons[3]);
    }  

    /**
     * Read in the data from the database to the arrays.
     * @param 
     */
    public void readData(String[] questions, String[] answers) {
        //System.out.println("First read: " + currentQuestion + 5);

        questions[0] = "Question 1";
        questions[1] = "Question 2";

        for(int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            questions[i] = "Question " + (i + 1);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
            answers[i] = "Answer" + (i + 1);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i+= 4) {
            correctAnswers[i] = 0;
            correctAnswers[i + 1] = 1;
            correctAnswers[i + 2] = 2;
            correctAnswers[i + 3] = 3;
        }

        /*answers[0] = "Answer 1";
        answers[1] = "Answer 2";
        answers[2] = "Answer 3";
        answers[3] = "Answer 4";
        answers[4] = "Answer 5";
        answers[5] = "Answer 6";
        answers[6] = "Answer 7";
        answers[7] = "Answer 8";*/
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Moves onto the next question and prepares the data for read-in
     * Assign the next question to the text field
     * Assign the next answers to the buttons
     */
    public void moveOntoNextQuestion(String questions[], String[] answers, JButton[] answerButtons) {
        //System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-moveOntoNextQuestion-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
        String nextQuestion = questions[currentQuestion];
        questionText.setText(questions[currentQuestion]);

        //System.out.println("The current question is " + questions[currentQuestion]);
        //System.out.println("The current answer number is " + currentAnswer);
        answerButtons[0].setText(answers[currentAnswer]);
        answerButtons[1].setText(answers[currentAnswer + 1]);
        answerButtons[2].setText(answers[currentAnswer + 2]);
        answerButtons[3].setText(answers[currentAnswer + 3]);
        //System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");

    }

    /**
     * @param answer
     * Check if the clicked answer was correct.
     */
    public void checkCorrectQuestion(JButton[] answerButtons) {
        int correctAnswer = correctAnswers[currentQuestion];
        //System.out.println("Current correct answer is " + correctAnswer);

        answerButtons[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(correctAnswer == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Button 1 is correct!");

                        score += 10;
                        updateScore(scoreCounter);

                        try {
                            correctAnswerAlterEgo(alterEgoImage, alterEgoImageLabel);
                        } catch(IOException excep) {
                            // Handle the error here
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Button 1 is wrong!");
                        score -= 5;
                        updateScore(scoreCounter);
                    }

                    updateQuestionAndAnswer();
                    
                    //currentQuestion += 1;
                    //System.out.println("currentQuestion value is " + currentQuestion);
                    //currentAnswer += 4;

                    //System.out.println("This is the quizLoop for button 1");
                    quizLoop(questions, answers, answerButtons);

                }
            });

        
**WITHIN HERE ARE THE OTHER THREE ACTION LISTENERS FOR THE BUTTONS. THEY ARE THE EXACT SAME EXCEPT [1], [2] and [3].**


    }
    
    public void updateQuestionAndAnswer() {
        currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
        currentAnswer = currentAnswer + 4;
    }

    public void updateScore(JLabel scoreCounter) {
        scoreCounter.setText("<html><span style='font-size:30px;'>Score: " + String.valueOf(score) + "</html>");
    }

    public void correctAnswerAlterEgo(BufferedImage alterEgoImage, JLabel alterEgoImageLabel) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Correct answer alter ego method called!");
        scoreCounter.setText("<html><span style='font-size:30px;'>TEST: </html>");

        // Images
        BufferedImage[] happyImages = new BufferedImage[]{ ImageIO.read(new File("AlterEgo/excited.jpeg")), ImageIO.read(new File("AlterEgo/happy.jpeg")), ImageIO.read(new File("AlterEgo/shocked.jpeg"))};

        alterEgoImage = ImageIO.read(new File("AlterEgo/class78.jpg"));

        alterEgoImageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(alterEgoImage));

        card2.add(alterEgoImageLabel);
        card2.remove(alterEgoImageLabel);
    }

    public void wrongAnswerAlterEgo() {

    }```


Thank you for your help,
````

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `addActionListener` and see how many times it is called.

Comment: I think you should try to post the minimal amount of code that reproduces your problem. I refer you to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 1) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 2) This typically happens when you keep adding an ActionListener to your button. 2) *defined to 0 or "" in a static context * - don't use static variables. 3) *but then question 4, 8, 16...* - this can happen when you keep adding an ActionListener to your button. So the main suggestion is don't keep creating new components. All you need is a panel containing all the Swing components needed for the question/answer. Then you have a "refresh()" method that simply changes the text of the question and the valid answer.

Comment: How would I fix the action listeners being added each time, without having to re-do the whole project?